# Graph theory: name for a strongly connected component where every edge is bidirectional?

Tags: graph-theory, terminology, directed-graphs

Hi :) I was wondering if there is a term for a strongly connected component in a directed graph where every edge in the component is bidirectional. E.g. Graph1 would qualify, but graph2 would not, despite the fact Graph2 is strongly connected.

Graph1:
edge(1, 2),
edge(2, 1),
edge(2, 3),
edge(3, 2),

Graph2:
edge(1, 2),
edge(2, 3),
edge(3, 1),

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not aware of anything other than what you wrote: "strongly connected component where every edge is bidirectional" [sorry]. In general, if you are writing up math, you can almost never go wrong by spelling out what you mean.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: If all of them are bidirectional, that is just an undirected graph and its called a connected component

Comment: I might call it a "bidirected component". Or you could define the auxiliary graph whose edges are the bidirected edges of your digraph. But I don't think there is a standard name.

Comment: Thanks for all the help! @JBL - that's a great idea, and exactly what I was looking for. Thank you :)